# google maps displaying white screen on Android phone (ionic 3)

Tags: ionic3, screen

I'm using ionic 3 and my map displays fine on a desktop browser; however, it's showing a white screen on Android phones (I am using IONIC DEV-APP to run it on my phone).

Answer (score 0):

`IONIC DEV-APP` does not contain the `cordova-plugin-googlemaps`
https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/view.html#plugin-support

The tutorial is kind of old. Check out the official document.
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1zlkmoSY4AzDJc_P4IqWLnzct41IqHyzGkLeyhlAxMDE/edit#slide=id.p